# Hacer una index como la de TWITTER

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox

Quiero crear una index casi identica, estoy usando bootstrap para realizarla, me tropese con el comienzo del sitio, ya que no puedo colocar los dos Divs que contienen texto y el form, ocupan el 50% del sitio con width pero cuando quiero que ocupen el 100% de altura no lo hace, en twitter vi que no importa cuanto le retire de zoom siempre esta ocupando el 100% de Height.

He visto que ellos usan Flexbox en algunos divs, he intentado copiar exactamente pero no me funciona.

```css
.izquierdo {
 background-color: #449dd1;
}

.derecho {
 background-color: #78c0e0;
}

.pie {
 background-color: white;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6ecf0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <!-- Etiqueta para responsive -->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <!-- Hoja de estilos de bootstrap -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Este es todo el contenido -->
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <section class="main row">
  <!-- Es donde se encuentra el fondo de la pàgina el lado izquierdo -->
  <div class="izquierdo col-md-6">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et dolorem libero corrupti, ea expedita ex est laudantium minus ad, magnam asperiores, velit quasi nostrum, cumque sequi nam assumenda dignissimos quo.
  </div>
  <!-- Es donde se encuentra el login -->
  <div class="derecho col-md-6">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quas cupiditate quia ad quisquam, autem recusandae facere distinctio! Sint quibusdam nisi quis non dignissimos soluta voluptatum impedit consectetur quasi corporis.
  </div>
 </section>
 </div>

 <!-- Es el pie de pàgina no tendra casi nada pero bue -->
 <footer class="pie">
  
 </footer>

 <!-- El pinche jquery -->
 <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```